# Phone number as a hyperlink bot framework c#

Tags: c#, chatbot, botframework

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("<a href=\"tel:+62896706255135\">Call me at +62-896-7062-55135</a>"), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I am using bot framework web chat channel and I want to send clickable phone number to user but it doesn't render html anchor tag.

Comment: I think `tel` protocol should have the `//` just like `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://` ... try `tel://` with your href.

Comment: @Filburt u mean like this -MessageFactory.Text("tel://+62896706255135")

Comment: Yes, that's how I'd expect it should work - I don't have the means to test myself so I just commented and not put as an answer.

Comment: @Filburt I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: [Process Events with rich cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#process-events-within-rich-cards) shows you can use the `call` type - this one uses the notation without `//`.

Comment: @Filburt it just shows as a text actually I m not using any card here

Comment: Does the `<a href="">` work if you use a website URL? I missed that you mentioned you tried the URL without the `<a>` html element.

Comment: @ABHINAYYADAV - Did you mean to say you're using Web Chat? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes I am using Web Chat

Comment: @KyleDelaney I already tried [Call me at +62-896-7062-55135](tel:+62896706255135) this markdown syntax but it doesn't work  with a webchat channel

Comment: If you don't say what you've already tried beforehand then you're asking people to waste their time and yours. Markdown is the correct way to do this and it works in Web Chat, so please provide screenshots and code samples that actually show what you're doing, and include your Web Chat code. Read this document to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ABHINAYYADAV = Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I failed to achieve this, so I go with the adaptive card

Comment: @ABHINAYYADAV - Would you like to post that as an answer, or would you like to accept mine?

Answer (score 1):

Use Markdown syntax.

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("[Call me at +62-896-7062-55135](tel:+62896706255135)"), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```